# Pcre php regex equal in c++

Tags: c++, regex

hello this is pcre regex (php regex)

```
/\h*(.*?)\h*[=]\h*("(.*?(?:[\\\\]".*?)*)")\h*([,|.*?])/
```

this regex work for this string

```
data1 = "value 1",   data2 = "value 2",  data3 = " data4(" hey ") ",
```

and get

```
data, data2, data3
 val, val2, data4("val3")
```

what is this regex equal in c++ regex ?

Comment: Replace `\h` with `\s`. If you use a raw string, use ``\\`` instead of ``\\\\``. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ3uC4/1).

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `\h` with `\s` and use `\\` inside a raw string literal.

Refer to the following example code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string pat = R"(\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(\"(.*?(?:[\\]\".*?)*)\")\s*([,|.*?]))";
    std::regex r(pat);
    std::cout << pat << "\n";

    std::string s = R"(data1 = "value 1",   data2 = "value 2",  data3 = " data4(" hey ") ",)";
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << "Capture 1: " << m[1].str() << " at Position " << m.position(1) << '\n';
        std::cout << "Capture 3: " << m[3].str() << " at Position " << m.position(3) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/JJYDOH) and a JS (ECMA5) [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ3uC4/1)